Vue 2.7 - Vuex no bindea mi store en el componente hijo
Os comento el problema rapidamente:
Tengo mi vista : miVista:
que tiene un componente :
.....
.....
 <question-maker v-if="loaded" v-show="question.show"/>
.....
.....

Con su correspondiente :
  ...mapState({
      user: "user",
      question: "question"  // <-- aqui lo tengo bindeado y funcionando OK !
    }),


question es un store que en la vista funciona bien . Ahora, ese mismo store llamado question tambien pretendo manejarlo en el componente question-maker , por lo que dentro de este vuelvo a llamar al store , pero en este caso me da undefined , es decir, en la vista si lee el store, pero en el componente hijo no, esto no deberia de pasar.
En el componente hijo, he llamado tambien al mapeo mapState que tengo arriba, pero me da undefine, y ahora estaba probando con algo asi , pero tampoco va:
 ...mapState({
      type: state => state.question.type
    }),

Para dar contexto sobre como es este store, lo dejo a continuacion:
import proxy from "@/proxy";

const question = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => ({
    type: "free", // 1 = Free Text || 2 = Options
    title: '',
    answer: '',
    show: false,
    new_answer: '',
    list: [],
  }),
  mutations: {
    setType: function(state,type){
      state.type = type;
    },
    setTitle: function(state,title){
      state.title = title;
    },
    addAnswer: function(state){
      state.list.push(state.new_answer);
    },

    reset: function(state){
      state.type = 'free';
      state.title = '';
      state.answer = '';
      state.show = false;
      state.new_answer = '';
      state.list = [];
    },
    openModal: function(state){
      console.log('open questions modal');
      state.show = true;
    },
    closeModal: function(state){
      console.log('close questions modal');
      state.show = false;
    }
    
  },
  actions: {
  },
};

export default question;

Tengo como 10 modulos de store y ninguno me habia dado problema, no se a este que le pasa, me pierdo el motivo de porque no es alcanzable en el componente hijo.

Prueba usando
...mapState('question', {
  type: state => state.type
}),

o
...mapState('question', ['type']),


Buenas, gracias por contestar. El problema era de codigo, tenia dos computed . Cierro la pregutna. Gracias ! :)
